# Does make/gmake include all the libraries after built?

Tags: nginx, lua, centos, rpm, openresty

I was building the openresty Nginx on machine A and want to use it on machine B. Is it necessary to install all the rpm/dependencies on machine B?

The building process on machine A is like:

1. yum install multiple-devel commands
2. git clone multiple repositories
3. wget openresty.tar.gz
4. untar openresty, cd openresty and `./configure --...`
5. gmake
6. gmake install

---

When I tried to understand the relationships between `configure`, `make` and `make install`, I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/54628708/11887927 but still not quite get it.

If it's still required to install all the rpm&dependencies, what's the benefit of building on my own or I'm totally wrong about the `make` process?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't make myself clear enough. Thanks for anyone stopping by.

#### Machine B doesn't require rpm/dependencies but needs libraries built on machine A

Here is how it works:

1. copy Nginx binary/configurations to B
2. copy libraries(including folders, openresty in my case) to B
3. echo libraries to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`, `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/luajit.conf` in my case